# Indent a Proto file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, proto

Is there a way to auto indent Proto file code in Visual Studio.
For example, C# code can be indented but proto file isnt getting indented in visual studio 2019. Thanks

Comment: It's annoying that something so extremely C-like doesn't have a formatter in VS.  If you're open to using VsCode, the `vscode-proto3` extension can do it for you.

Comment: @NPras ok i ll try and give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NPras. I was able to format a proto file using vscode-proto3. Clang-Format also works as an extension in Vs Code. The clang-format needs to be in system path for both the extensions to work.

clang-format extension can be downloaded from here: https://llvm.org/builds/